# SQL Query for combining two tables even if certain fields are blank empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

### Table 1 (T1)

VchID CustomerID Amt
1   ----  1  ----      100.00
2   ----  1  ----      200.00
3   ----  2  ----      250.00
2   ----  NULL  ----      200.00

### Table2  (T2)

CustID CustomerName
1 ---- ABC
2 ---- XYZ

### I want the following result :

VchID CustomerName
1   ----  ABC
2   ----  ABC
3   ----  XYZ
2   ----  NULL

When i use the following query, the Null row is left out. How to include that.

```
Select T1.VchID, T2.CustomerName 
FROM  Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
WHERE T1.CustomerID = T2.CustID
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: [Using Outer Joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `outer join` instead:

```
SELECT T1.VchID, T2.CustomerName 
FROM Table1 T1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CustomerID = T2.CustID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/867dda/1)
- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)